# $sth->execute(array(type string doesn't seem to work));

Tags: php

I am not sure but for some reason when I fetch this query, i always get bool(false) result.

This is the partial php script for this

```
// Check if the name is available.
$sql = "SELECT count(*) as nameCount FROM {$server->charMapDatabase}.`name` where name = ?";
$sth = $server->connection->getStatement($sql);
$sth->execute(array("adrian"));
$query = $sth->fetch();
var_dump($query);
```

The value of $query is bool(false) even the result is more than 1, 0.

am I doing it in wrong way?

Comment: What's `getStatement`?  Are you using PDO or MySQLi?

Comment: Add `setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION)` right after the connection is opened if you're not already checking for errors.

Comment: false probably means something failed previously, and since you've failed to check for failure, that failure is trickling on down the line. NEVER assume success with a database operation. Always assume failure, check for it, and treat success as a pleasant surprise.

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys I found my mistake, I'm using the wrong table. I mistakenly type in name instead of char. I don't know why its showing any error as i'm using a non existing table.

It should be

```
// Check if the name is available.
$sql = "SELECT count(*) as nameCount FROM {$server->charMapDatabase}.`char` where name = ?";
$sth = $server->connection->getStatement($sql);
$sth->execute(array("adrian"));
$query = $sth->fetch();
var_dump($query);
```